# Let netlify use a subdomain thats also used on a different site

Tags: subdomain, netlify

(how) is this possible:

I have 2 netlify sites `main-app` and `sub-app`.

`main-app` has a custom domain ([www.main.com](http://www.main.com)).

I now want to make the 2nd site `sub-app` using the custom domain `sub.main.com` but Netlify forbids this and notes that I already use the respecity domain `main.com`.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use subdomains. It is discussed in detail in their docs: https://docs.netlify.com/domains-https/custom-domains/

You already have a Netlify subdomain where your app is hosted, of type myapp.netlify.app. Now you need to point your subdomain to this instance. If you use for example Namecheap, you do it like this: https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9776/2237/how-to-create-a-subdomain-for-my-domain/

Here is Netlify's instructions for doing this if you don't host your domain with them (aka not using Netlify DNS) https://docs.netlify.com/domains-https/custom-domains/configure-external-dns/

Similar DNS editing as in Namechrap will be seen on all other domain hosts. Once this is set up and has had time to propagate (give it 10 minutes to an hour) you proceed with hooking it up in Netlify. Your error message should now be gone.

Remember that you need different DNS records on your domain host for the main app and the sub app.

Comment: When i add a subdomain to my 2nd site i get
`Another site is already using this domain`

Comment: I have updated my answer with more info about pointing your domains to the apps on Netlify.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a subdomain in the netlify panel and in you DNS manager / hosting provider add the records as CNAME with the domain provided by netlify.